# How to deal with forms: <input> and <select> in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on a cross-device app with AngularJS and Cordova, but I'm having trouble dealing with CSS of form elements. I need to use a basic select, multiple select, input with date and input with time in my form. The problems I'm having are:

1. Multiple select - how to add a placeholder text and how to change the text that displays after i select multiple options (ie. `"Please select your options"` -> `"Option 1, Option 5"` or -> `"4 Options selected"`)
2. `<input>` with `type="date"` and `type="time"` - I'm unable to change their CSS on Android devices (line-height, padding, width, height, etc.). Whatever I do they seem to stay "default"

Also worth mentioning I'd like the `<select>` to call native select. I don't have problem with dynamically changing text, but with it's placement.

I googled a bit and jquery mobile has this [jQueryMobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) which has everything I need, but I don't want to load whole jQuery mobile just for this + if I load it, I'll have to write a lot of additional CSS because jQuery mobiles CSS is quite greedy.

Comment: for multiple select, i recommend you to use chosen (the jquery plugin). You can see multiple selection, customize placeholder, design your own style.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to avoid multiselect. Android shows only one item when selected more than one item. Ios show "1 item selected" but behaviour is not consistent.

I give you 2 options: If there are few try to put a list of checkboxes. If number is high you can navigate to a child list of a scroll of checkboxes.

2) For dates I recommend use a plug-in like http://plugreg.com/plugin/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker

Comment: 1.) Can't avoid multiselect, designer and customer demand it, I have to make it work somehow.
2.) Thanks, will try it out.

Comment: This actually doesn't help me, I'm developing for WP8, android and iOS, can't rely on a plugin.